# A system of nonlinear partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, nonlinear-system

Here are non-linear partial differential equations, where $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x,t$ :

$g^2 (\partial_{x}f)(\partial_{t}f) - (\partial_{x}g) (\partial_{t}g) = 0, \quad g^{2}(\partial_{x}f)^{2} - (\partial_{x}g)^{2} = -1 , \quad g^{2}(\partial_{t}f)^{2} - (\partial_{t}g)^{2} = 1 .$

A "simple" solution is known , in fact the inverse expression of $x,t$ in function of $f,g$ is even "simpler".

Now, I am looking to the more logic, the more rigorous, and the most simple demonstration, which allows  to find this "simple" solution.

Comment: Present the least logical/rigorous/simple demo yourself first, maybe?

Comment: @automaton : This question is originally a physics problem, which, in its context, may be resolved easily. However, some people prefer using "brute force" and this set of differential equations. I wondered how to do that. The "least logical/rigorous/simple"  would mean give the solution, as "guessed", and I did not want to give this solution, to not influence people, and to see how math fellows are able to solve this problem from scratch. A little hint is to solve $g$ then $f$

Comment: Fair enough. You might have to reconsider, as the question does not seem for raise enough interest, but that's really your call. I'll see what I can do if I find the time, under the condition that you'll contribute the missing context after a reply has been offered. (Might use for homework :).)

Comment: @automaton3 : The physics [link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/79194/6316) is here (with one "guessed" answer and a more elabore answer) so please don't look at them before your calculus!